# When using Node.js with the graph API I can't seem to add the @odata.id to the object

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have been programming a node.js Java script to look at MSFT graph info. I am trying to post an owner to a group which I can get working with the Https post on the web site. However I am getting an error when I try to run the Node Is code. I seem to be having an issue with the object :

```
const directoryObject = {
  @odata.id: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
};
```

JavaScript does not seem to like the @ or the in the object key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

JavaScript code snippet :

const options = {
authProvider,
};

```
const client = Client.init(options);

 const directoryObject = {
  @odata.id: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
};

let res = await client.api('/groups/{id}/owners/$ref')
    .post(directoryObject);
```

Many Thanks

Dominic

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I managed to get things working although I am not sure what fixed it, but I did 3 things:

1. The Microsoft Node. JS code doesn't work and you just need to put speech marks in so it looks like :

   const directoryObject = {
   "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
   };
2. I also added the odata module :

   npm install odata

   There is more info here :

   1.https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata
   2.http://olingo.apache.org/doc/javascript/apidoc/json.html
   3.https://www.odata.org/getting-started/understand-odata-in-6-steps/
   4.https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/
3. I used the .post example from the MSFT graph example for posting a calendar event and adapted it. I also  didn't check for the html response in code, looked at the terminal response and checked the behaviour in Teams.